# Import Error: No module named Error on the same path

Tags: python

I tried to create a simple program and import it to a different file.

file1.py is:

```
class GreetingCard:
    def __init__(self, recipient="Dana Ev", sender="Eyal Ch"):
        self._recipient = recipient
        self._sender = sender

    def greeting_msg(self):
        print("Recipient: {}, Sender: {}".format(self._recipient, self._sender))


def main():
    card = GreetingCard("John", "Tommy")
    card.greeting_msg()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I try to import the module to file2.py in the same directory, it doesn't work...

file2.py is:

```
import file1


class BirthdayCard(GreetingCard):
    def __init__(self, recipient, sender, age=0):
        super().__init__(recipient, sender)
        self._age = age

    def greeting_msg(self):
        super().greeting_msg()
        print("Happy birthday, I'm {} years old!".format(self._age))
```

running this file shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/משתמש/Desktop/nextPy/6.2.5/file2.py", line 3, in <module>
    class BirthdayCard(GreetingCard):
NameError: name 'GreetingCard' is not defined
```

Comment: try switching `import file1` to `from file1 import GreetingCard`, or use `file1.GreetingCard` in your file2 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`from file1 import GreetingCard`

Answer (score 0):

If you want try importing GreetingCard
Like

```
from ---- import greetingCard
```